# Coded UI vs Protractor

Tags: automated-testing, visualstudio, tfs, mtm, protractor

I just joined a new company who doesn't work with any kind of automated tests. I have been hired to start test automation, and looking around I found two interesting options to e2e tests, Protractor and CodedUI, but I have not found any big reasons to use either Protractor or CodedUI (well, we do use TFS).

Can anyone help me? I liked Protractor, but if decide to go with it, I have to find a way to integrate those tests with Microsoft Test Manager to run against an environment managed by SCVMM. On the other hand, CodedUI tests don't look very friendly.

Comment: Are we talking about this Protractor: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/ ?

Comment: Based on what factors, you have shortlisted Protractor and Coded UI?

Comment: What is your tech stack?

Answer (score 4):

If it is an Angular application I would go for Protractor

EDIT:

Protractor was made for Angular Apps. You don't have deal with elements not being visible yet due to page loads. Protractors deals with it for you

As far as I know CodedUI des not provide this functionality. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Resource reason:
Most Angular projects are javascript intensive. Which means your devs will be able to maintain the protractor tests too. Might come in handy later.

Comment: I second the vote for protractor, if the application is made with Angular

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into TestComplete? We use it at my company and have found it to be very versatile and the SmartBear folks are excellent to work with.

http://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/features/

Answer (score 0):

From the research i have done into automation for our company from a QA side the criteria of which i judged each company was cost efficiency and ability to handle our needs. On the cost effective side i believe selenium is free. My favorite out of everything was Telerik hands down. They are very professional, helpful support, and great in terms of handling controls(i.e name changes etc). Telerik also integrates with TFS you can find out more about that [here](http://www.telerik.com/teampulse/tfs) . They also integrate with MTM as you stated you needed that as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, i dont think our company will buy Telerik once they had experienced some trouble with telerik and past employees. It must to be a REALLY good reason to buy once again instead using protractor or codedui :\

Comment: Have you looked into HP they seemed to be running 2nd in comparison to Telerik?

http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/unified-functional-automated-testing/index.html

Comment: not yet, i will take a look : )

Answer (score 0):

It will completely depend on which technology you are using for e2e testing.

If e2e is based on windows product then i would suggest to go for Coded UI. 
If it is web based then it would be great to go with selenium.

It is selection is completely based on requirement of automation too.

Answer (score 0):

If not protractor, why not use C# implementation of Selenium. I am not familiar with TFS or MTM, but I am sure they will be having some easy integration options with Selenium Webdriver running with C# client.
Before going to the costly options, try Selenium which is a very efficient and commonly used web application test automation tool.

Answer (score 0):

First of all gather all requirement to automate particular application. From all aspect like:

1. What is application
2. Test coverage to automate
3. Frequency of test execution
4. Reporting

Then after based on requirement go with the tool selection.

- If your application is completely web based and should be tested on cross browser on different environment then you can go with Selenium and Protractor
- If your application is desktop/web based but only will be tested on windows environment then you should go with Coded-UI.

I have used both Selenium as well as Coded-UI. Coded-UI is little bit complex to start with but once you understand core concepts you will find it easy to use and maintain all test cases.